# How to push a view in tab bar application from appDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a tab bar application with 4 tabs. And when a user clicks a button on one of the views on one of the tabs, I run a method of an appDelegate. In that method I want to display a view over my tab bar application. I want to do it in appDelegate because I have several buttons of one type and I want to implement one method for them so that different views will share one instance of a class. This is how I tried to do it, but all these attempts didn't work:

```
-(void)authorizeTwitter{
if(!_engine){  
    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];  
    _engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;  
    _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  
}

if(![_engine isAuthorized]){  
    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];  

    if (controller){
        //[self.rootController presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
        //[self.window addSubview:controller.view];
        //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        //[controller.view showFromTabBar:self.rootController.tabBar];

    }  
}
```

}

controller - is a viewController instance and I want to show controller.view over my tab bar and all views

Comment: Generally as much viewControllers are created as required and added to the array and then the tabBarcontroller is initiated with these viewcontrollers. It is done in appDelegate (only once). I cant get u. Why do u want to call it from appDelegate for every tab ?

Comment: Opps, sorry. Somehow this line 

    [self.rootController presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];

began working. Now twitter authorizing page is displayed properly. Anyway, thanks for your attempts.

Comment: Fine ! Go ahead then...Happy Coding ! :) cheers

Comment: Probably it didn't run before because of interruption of some type: view tries to show but code after displaying view interrupts it. I separated the code of authorizations from other code and made a different method and it began to work.